# How to change Springfox SwaggerUI serialization for java.time.Period?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, springfox

I have a Spring Boot REST service with this simplified build.gradle:

```properties
dependencies {
  implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
  implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb"
    
  implementation "io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0"
  implementation "io.springfox:springfox-bean-validators:3.0.0"
}
```

The REST service delivers a `java.time.Period` and a `java.time.LocalDateTime`. This is what I get when I do a GET:

```json
{
  "id": "6061d65898be1a421f795904",
  "myDate": "2021-03-29T15:30:00.604",
  "myPeriod": "P6M"
}
```

This is exactly what I want. POST, PUT and PATCH requests also accept exactly this format. However if I browse to the SwaggerUI /api/swagger-ui/index.html, the example json looks like this:

```json
{
  "id": "string",
  "myDate": "2021-03-31T10:40:35.172Z",
  "myPeriod": {
    "chronology": {
      "calendarType": "string",
      "id": "string"
    },
    "days": 0,
    "months": 0,
    "negative": true,
    "units": [
      {
        "dateBased": true,
        "duration": {
          "nano": 0,
          "negative": true,
          "seconds": 0,
          "units": [
            null
          ],
          "zero": true
        },
        "durationEstimated": true,
        "timeBased": true
      }
    ],
    "years": 0,
    "zero": true
  },
}
```

Obviously it serializes the `java.time.Period` as a full object, not as a string. The `java.time.LocalDateTime` is handled properly. This becomes a problem when trying to do a POST, PUT or PATCH request with this example code, the service logs this:

> Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected VALUE_STRING; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected VALUE_STRING

Any idea how I can change the Springfox SwaggerUI serialization?